# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe' with hvPlot and datashade

Tags: python, bokeh, datashader, hvplot, holoviz

I've try using this tutorial https://holoviz.org/tutorial/Basic_Plotting.html to use datashade in hvPlot, but with personnal data.

I can show my plot with `df.hvplot.scatter(x='col1', y='col2', datashade=False)` for n number of line, but when I try to use datashade with `df.hvplot.scatter(x='col1', y='col2', datashade=True)` , I have this error:

```
Invoked as dynamic_operation(height=300, scale=1.0, width=700, x_range=None, y_range=None)
WARNING:param.dynamic_operation: Callable raised "TypeError("Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'")".
Invoked as dynamic_operation(height=300, scale=1.0, width=700, x_range=None, y_range=None)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\dimension.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, include, exclude)
   1302         combined and returned.
   1303         """
-> 1304         return Store.render(self)
   1305 
   1306 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\options.py in render(cls, obj)
   1393         data, metadata = {}, {}
   1394         for hook in hooks:
-> 1395             ret = hook(obj)
   1396             if ret is None:
   1397                 continue

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in pprint_display(obj)
    280     if not ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].pprint:
    281         return None
--> 282     return display(obj, raw_output=True)
    283 
    284 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in display(obj, raw_output, **kwargs)
    256     elif isinstance(obj, (HoloMap, DynamicMap)):
    257         with option_state(obj):
--> 258             output = map_display(obj)
    259     elif isinstance(obj, Plot):
    260         output = render(obj)

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in wrapped(element)
    144         try:
    145             max_frames = OutputSettings.options['max_frames']
--> 146             mimebundle = fn(element, max_frames=max_frames)
    147             if mimebundle is None:
    148                 return {}, {}

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in map_display(vmap, max_frames)
    204         return None
    205 
--> 206     return render(vmap)
    207 
    208 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in render(obj, **kwargs)
     66         renderer = renderer.instance(fig='png')
     67 
---> 68     return renderer.components(obj, **kwargs)
     69 
     70 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py in components(self, obj, fmt, comm, **kwargs)
    374             doc = Document()
    375             with config.set(embed=embed):
--> 376                 model = plot.layout._render_model(doc, comm)
    377             if embed:
    378                 return render_model(model, comm)

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\panel\viewable.py in _render_model(self, doc, comm)
    415         if comm is None:
    416             comm = state._comm_manager.get_server_comm()
--> 417         model = self.get_root(doc, comm)
    418 
    419         if config.embed:

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\panel\viewable.py in get_root(self, doc, comm)
    640         """
    641         doc = doc or _curdoc()
--> 642         root = self._get_model(doc, comm=comm)
    643         self._preprocess(root)
    644         ref = root.ref['id']

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\panel\layout.py in _get_model(self, doc, root, parent, comm)
    118         if root is None:
    119             root = model
--> 120         objects = self._get_objects(model, [], doc, root, comm)
    121         props = dict(self._init_properties(), objects=objects)
    122         model.update(**self._process_param_change(props))

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\panel\layout.py in _get_objects(self, model, old_objects, doc, root, comm)
    108             else:
    109                 try:
--> 110                     child = pane._get_model(doc, root, model, comm)
    111                 except RerenderError:
    112                     return self._get_objects(model, current_objects[:i], doc, root, comm)

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\holoviews.py in _get_model(self, doc, root, parent, comm)
    225             plot = self.object
    226         else:
--> 227             plot = self._render(doc, comm, root)
    228 
    229         plot.pane = self

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\holoviews.py in _render(self, doc, comm, root)
    284             kwargs = {}
    285 
--> 286         return renderer.get_plot(self.object, **kwargs)
    287 
    288     def _cleanup(self, root):

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\bokeh\renderer.py in get_plot(self_or_cls, obj, doc, renderer, **kwargs)
     71         combining the bokeh model with another plot.
     72         """
---> 73         plot = super(BokehRenderer, self_or_cls).get_plot(obj, doc, renderer, **kwargs)
     74         if plot.document is None:
     75             plot.document = Document() if self_or_cls.notebook_context else curdoc()

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py in get_plot(self_or_cls, obj, doc, renderer, comm, **kwargs)
    209 
    210         # Initialize DynamicMaps with first data item
--> 211         initialize_dynamic(obj)
    212 
    213         if not renderer:

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\util.py in initialize_dynamic(obj)
    249             continue
    250         if not len(dmap):
--> 251             dmap[dmap._initial_key()]
    252 
    253 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1278         # Not a cross product and nothing cached so compute element.
   1279         if cache is not None: return cache
-> 1280         val = self._execute_callback(*tuple_key)
   1281         if data_slice:
   1282             val = self._dataslice(val, data_slice)

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in _execute_callback(self, *args)
   1052 
   1053         with dynamicmap_memoization(self.callback, self.streams):
-> 1054             retval = self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
   1055         return self._style(retval)
   1056 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    691 
    692         try:
--> 693             ret = self.callable(*args, **kwargs)
    694         except KeyError:
    695             # KeyError is caught separately because it is used to signal

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs)
    983 
    984         def dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs):
--> 985             key, obj = resolve(key, kwargs)
    986             return apply(obj, *key, **kwargs)
    987 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in resolve(key, kwargs)
    976             elif isinstance(map_obj, DynamicMap) and map_obj._posarg_keys and not key:
    977                 key = tuple(kwargs[k] for k in map_obj._posarg_keys)
--> 978             return key, map_obj[key]
    979 
    980         def apply(element, *key, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1278         # Not a cross product and nothing cached so compute element.
   1279         if cache is not None: return cache
-> 1280         val = self._execute_callback(*tuple_key)
   1281         if data_slice:
   1282             val = self._dataslice(val, data_slice)

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in _execute_callback(self, *args)
   1052 
   1053         with dynamicmap_memoization(self.callback, self.streams):
-> 1054             retval = self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
   1055         return self._style(retval)
   1056 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    691 
    692         try:
--> 693             ret = self.callable(*args, **kwargs)
    694         except KeyError:
    695             # KeyError is caught separately because it is used to signal

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs)
    984         def dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs):
    985             key, obj = resolve(key, kwargs)
--> 986             return apply(obj, *key, **kwargs)
    987 
    988         operation = self.p.operation

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in apply(element, *key, **kwargs)
    980         def apply(element, *key, **kwargs):
    981             kwargs = dict(util.resolve_dependent_kwargs(self.p.kwargs), **kwargs)
--> 982             return self._process(element, key, kwargs)
    983 
    984         def dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in _process(self, element, key, kwargs)
    962         elif isinstance(self.p.operation, Operation):
    963             kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in self.p.operation.param}
--> 964             return self.p.operation.process_element(element, key, **kwargs)
    965         else:
    966             return self.p.operation(element, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in process_element(self, element, key, **params)
    170             self.p = param.ParamOverrides(self, params,
    171                                           allow_extra_keywords=self._allow_extra_keywords)
--> 172         return self._apply(element, key)
    173 
    174 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in _apply(self, element, key)
    130         element_pipeline = getattr(element, '_pipeline', None)
    131 
--> 132         ret = self._process(element, key)
    133         for hook in self._postprocess_hooks:
    134             ret = hook(self, ret, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\operation\datashader.py in _process(self, element, key)
   1435     def _process(self, element, key=None):
   1436         agg = rasterize._process(self, element, key)
-> 1437         shaded = shade._process(self, agg, key)
   1438         return shaded
   1439 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\holoviews\operation\datashader.py in _process(self, element, key)
   1267                 return RGB(img, **params)
   1268             else:
-> 1269                 img = tf.shade(array, **shade_opts)
   1270         return RGB(self.uint32_to_uint8_xr(img), **params)
   1271 

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\datashader\transfer_functions\__init__.py in shade(agg, cmap, color_key, how, alpha, min_alpha, span, name, color_baseline)
    509 
    510     if agg.ndim == 2:
--> 511         return _interpolate(agg, cmap, how, alpha, span, min_alpha, name)
    512     elif agg.ndim == 3:
    513         return _colorize(agg, color_key, how, alpha, span, min_alpha, name, color_baseline)

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\datashader\transfer_functions\__init__.py in _interpolate(agg, cmap, how, alpha, span, min_alpha, name)
    240     with np.errstate(invalid="ignore", divide="ignore"):
    241         # Transform data (log, eq_hist, etc.)
--> 242         data = interpolater(data, mask)
    243 
    244         # Transform span

~\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz-tutorial\lib\site-packages\datashader\transfer_functions\__init__.py in eq_hist(data, mask, nbins)
    171         if data2.dtype.kind == 'u':
    172              data2 = data2.astype('i8')
--> 173         hist = np.bincount(data2.ravel())
    174         bin_centers = np.arange(len(hist))
    175         idx = int(np.nonzero(hist)[0][0])

<__array_function__ internals> in bincount(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

All my data are in float64 in my dataframe, and I get the same error with 5 lines of data instead of 38k+. My 5 lines look like this :

```
        col1         col2
0    14.455556    72.211111
1     2.561111    11.222222
2     3.705556  2050.000000
3     3.816667    80.433333
4    18.919444  1993.586111
5     5.238889   249.433333
```

I am missing something? I've tries with index like the exemple, and index in datetime.

Comment: Can you try rasterize=True instead of datashade=True? That should work if it's just the shading code that is complaining, as it looks like above. Either way, please file a bug report at https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/issues with a reproducible example and a description of the platform you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've try with rasterize, and it is working, but I get a colorbar on the side, and a different type of datavisualisation (I forgot the word, but with different color for different quantity), wich is not applicable for the data I'm working with.

Comment: I think you can pass colorbar=False if you don't want a colorbar. If you don't want a colormap at all, you can pass cmap=["blue" ,"blue"], but you will lose most of the benefits of datashader if you do that.

Comment: Thank you, it work this way. I'll still search why datashade can't work the same way as multiple tutorial after.